# Add/Authorize Phone Numbers to Send SMS via the RingCentral API

Tags: sms, ringcentral

How can I authorize phone numbers to be able to send SMS via the API.

Calling `/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/sms` only allows me to send from one number (the main account #).

After review of the API and FAQ page I noticed another API call to Get a list of Phone numbers Authorized to send SMS `account/~/extension/~/phone-number`.  From the result set there's only one number.

How do I add/authorize numbers to that list?

Answer (score 1):

The `GET Extension Phone Number` List would return the list of phone numbers that are used by a particular extension. The numbers from that list would be mapped to a feature named:

```
"features": [
    "SmsSender",
    "MmsSender",
    "CallerId"
]
```

Which means you could filter the phone numbers on an extension to identify the numbers which could be used to send `SMS`. We do not have an API to edit the features on the phone number.

However, you could add numbers to your extension.

**Sandbox**

You can use sandbox numbers provided in Developer Portal. For additional numbers, you can add up to 4 numbers and extensions to your Sandbox Online account here: https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com/

Here is how you add numbers in the numbers to Sandbox Online account: [Adding a Digital Line](https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/5-10-Adding-Phones-to-other-extensions-via-Web?_ga=2.5947507.1369564287.1495122782-814475974.1495047576) (KB 3136)

**Production**

You are free to add as many numbers but the service web URL would be:
https://service.ringcentral.com/

Feel free to reach us out at [devsupport@ringcentral.com](http://devsupport@ringcentral.com) for additional support.